# When issuing ls in the /etc/ directory, I get "ls: reading directory .: Input/output error"

Tags: ls, etc

I have a Windows running a CentOS6 (32-bit) on a VMWare virtual machine. I am attemping to install a single-node Cloudera Hadoop according to [these instructions](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Quick-Start/cdh4qs_topic_3_2.html).

At one point I was asked to issue

```
 for x in `cd /etc/init.d ; ls hadoop-hdfs-*` ; do sudo service $x start ; done
```

and I received the following error:

```
ls: cannot access hadoop-hdfs-*: No such file or directory
```

When I `cd` into my `/etc/` directory, and issue `ls`, I receive the following:

```
ls: reading directory .: Input/output error
```

From googling I learned that the `ls: reading directory .: Input/output error` can occur when hardware is failing. I don't think that is related to my problem, because the `/etc/` directory is the only place where I cannot issue an `ls`, plus I am on a virtual machine with a new computer.

```
df -h
```

produces

[image]

Comment: I/O error on a run-of-the-mill on-disk filesystem? I'd say your hardware is failing.

Comment: @Gilles so I'm running this on a VM on my new labtop. The host operating system is fine and I have never received and hardware failing errors. Do you know what could emulate this effect on a VM?

Answer (score 1):

Something is definitely up with your installation of CentOS and this VM. I would suspect that the options you've picked for the type of hardware that you want VMWare to emulate is the root of your issue.

The other thing I would check is that your VM has ample free diskspace. You can issue this command when inside the VM to determine the disk usage.

#### Example

```
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      429G  358G   49G  89% /
/dev/sda1              99M   33M   61M  36% /boot
tmpfs                 5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

Comment: Hi slm, would you look at my answer again? I was unable to run this command in the same environment. I decided to restart my virtual box which wiped the whole thing clean back to its original state. I've tried installing Hadoop again and got a different set of problems. But I'm still getting "input/output" errors. I made this VM take up 20g of hard disk space.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen - can you explain why it says centos livecd? Are you trying to run the VM using a live distro?